# Get last 6 month name in Array for Chartjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I was trying get last six months names dynamically in chart js as label

```
 var profitChart = {
    labels: ***** last six months name,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Profit",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(58,181,74,0.3)",
        borderColor: "rgba(58,181,74,0.80)",
        pointRadius: false,
        pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: profitdata,
      },
```

Comment: Store all names in an array, get the current month from `new Date().getMonth()` (which is already zero-based) and then just grab the _"last six"_ from the array

Comment: works but if you count backwards from now after January it's showing undefined

Comment: January = `0` -> `0 - 1 == -1`, but at index `-1` there's nothing -> `undefined`. You have to adjust the index in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array having months , use `getMonth()` of date object to get present month and `Array.slice()` to extract last 6 months.

```js
let months=["January","February","March","April","June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
let currentMonth=new Date().getMonth()
var profitChart = {
        labels:months.slice(currentMonth-6).concat(months.slice(0,currentMonth)),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Profit",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(58,181,74,0.3)",
            borderColor: "rgba(58,181,74,0.80)",
            pointRadius: false,
            pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: "profitdata",
      }]
      }
 console.log(profitChart)
```

Comment: Its incorrect. it returns `["April", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October"]` when the current month is November (I asked for last 6 months). So ig it is only working for starting months.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs the last n months, for any positive integer n you could do this:

```
const getLastNMonths = n => {           
        const d = new Date();
        const currentMonth = d.getMonth();
        const locale = 'en-GB';

        let result = [];
        for (let i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            d.setMonth(currentMonth - i);
            result.push(d.toLocaleDateString(locale, { month: 'long' }));
        }
        return result;
    };
```

In the OPs case they would need to use `getLastNMonths(6)` like this

```
var profitChart = {
    labels: getLastNMonths(6),
    //other properties
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can change the language by changing the locale parameter.  Or leave it as undefined to output the months according to local timezone and default locale.